# VBA Excel Hide Column based on ANY value present from range of rows

Tags: excel, vba

[image]I saw a post but couldn't comment that I was able to successfully use the VBA code for after hours of attempt. I am on a MAC.

chris neilsen wrote this solution for this post: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67222817/search-a-column-for-specific-value-and-then-hide-rows-if-value-is-found/67222962#67222962?newreg=4c3995ed8046477a97d07511124c7dcb)

I changed the original code from the link above to hide a column. It works if the value of 2 is present in my rows. However, the issue is if I change the next row to a 1, the first 2 found is ignored and the row is hidden again, as if the entire code is only focusing on the new value. Maybe the For each loop is wrong?

The goal of my sheet is a company quote form. Users will select pre-selected options (1 or 2 in this case), and the code is meant to search "If any value of 2 is found in any of these rows, display a conditional column for them to fill out). User forms is not available on my 365Mac version. This code works great except this one bug.

```vb
Private Sub Macro2(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim RangeOfInterest As Range
    Dim TargetRangeOfInterest As Range
    Dim cl As Range
    Dim SearchValue As Variant
    
    'I want to search for the value 2
    '~~~ you probably want to search for the number 2, not the string "2"
    SearchValue = 2
    
    Set RangeOfInterest = Me.Range("I13:I20") '<~~ adjust to suit your needs
    
    Set TargetRangeOfInterest = Application.Intersect(RangeOfInterest, Target)
    If Not TargetRangeOfInterest Is Nothing Then
        With Me.Columns("U").EntireColumn
            For Each cl In TargetRangeOfInterest.Cells
                If cl.Value2 = SearchValue Then
                    ' Reads are faster than Writes, so only change the Hidden state if required
                    If .Hidden Then
                        .Hidden = False 'I want to reveal the hidden row 10 if Value 2 is found
                    End If
                Else  'If there is no value of 2
                    If Not .Hidden Then
                        .EntireColumn.Hidden = True 'hide row 10
                    End If
                End If
            Next
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: "*the code is ridiculously limited in features*" What "features" did you expect? Why don't you add them by editing the code?

Comment: Sorry I meant, code features on mac in general are limited. For example, cannot add user form. Could just be I don't know how to code what I want or workaround, but a lot of online codes simply don't work vs on the work PC I have. That's more just my frustration showing through of trying to figure this out haha

Comment: Not sure I agree, I have a friend who was a "die hard" PC user who slagged macs as toys for years. Once he saw mine and then tried one he actually led a project to replace all the computers in our place with iMacs and is now an Apple convert.

Comment: How is the macro triggered and what parameter is passed to it?

Comment: Essentially there are 1-20 rows that start as blank. A user fills out 1 or 2 down the list. I am aiming for the above code to trigger on cell change, but still account for any cell in the specified range that has "2" as a value, new or old. 

Right now, if I type 1 or 2, the macro works. But If I proceed to the next row and type 1, it acts like any previous 2 is not there.

Comment: So, if the `Target` passed to it is the cell modified, your problem is `TargetRangeOfInterest = Application.Intersect(RangeOfInterest, Target)` doing this, your code will always iterate through modified cell only (test it while debugging)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### A Worksheet Change: Hide Column

**Sheet Module e.g. `Sheet1`**

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    HideMyColumn Target
End Sub
```

**Standard Module e.g. `Module1`**

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub HideMyColumn(ByVal Target As Range)
    
    Const TARGET_RANGE As String = "I13:I20"
    Const SEARCH_VALUE As Variant = 2
    Const HIDE_COLUMN As Variant = "U"
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Target.Worksheet
    Dim trg As Range: Set trg = ws.Range(TARGET_RANGE)
    Dim irg As Range: Set irg = Intersect(trg, Target)
    If irg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
       
    With ws.Columns(HIDE_COLUMN)
        If IsNumeric(Application.Match(SEARCH_VALUE, trg, 0)) Then
            If .Hidden Then .Hidden = False
        Else
            If Not .Hidden Then .Hidden = True
        End If
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you. I put that in, and this is the error I get: Pasting image into post.