# How can I ask the target Search to consider Multiple Variants in VBA code

Tags: excel, vba

A member[vbasic2008](/questions/tagged/vbasic2008) wrote [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75553838/vba-excel-hide-column-based-on-any-value-present-from-range-of-rows) VBA code for me on a different question, and I have one additional change I am wondering how to make. In this search, we are looking for any row in the specified range that has "2". I am wondering, how can I write this to look for 2 or 3, for example. I am changing this to actual words, but keeping the example simple for now. It works with one word, just not multiple.

I tried "2" Or "3", tried duplicating the search line item, but am not great with coding so figured I would ask the experts.

Comment: What "this VBA" should mean, please? Try editing your question and placing the code in it. Mentioning that it came from...

Comment: What code? What did you change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### A Worksheet Change: Hide Column (Multiple Criteria)

**Sheet Module e.g. `Sheet1`**

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    HideMyColumn Target
End Sub
```

**Standard Module e.g. `Module1`**

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub HideMyColumn(ByVal Target As Range)
    
    Const TARGET_RANGE As String = "I13:I20"
    Const HIDE_COLUMN As Variant = "U"
    Dim SearchValues(): SearchValues = Array(2, 3)
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Target.Worksheet
    Dim trg As Range: Set trg = ws.Range(TARGET_RANGE)
    Dim irg As Range: Set irg = Intersect(trg, Target)
    If irg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
       
    With ws.Columns(HIDE_COLUMN)
        If Application.Count(Application.Match(SearchValues, trg, 0)) > 0 Then
            If .Hidden Then .Hidden = False
        Else
            If Not .Hidden Then .Hidden = True
        End If
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you both, both versions work great! Lifesavers!!!!!!

Answer (score 2):

I looked into your profile and found the question in discussion...

Please, use the next adapted `Sub`:

```
Sub new_excel_file()

Dim InitialName As String
Dim sFileSaveName As Variant
InitialName = "Sample Output"
sFileSaveName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(InitialFileName:=InitialName, fileFilter:="Excel Files (*.xlsm), *.xlsm")

If sFileSaveName <> False Then
     Debug.Print sFileSaveName
    ActiveWorkbook.saveas sFileSaveName
End If

Sub HideMyColumn(ByVal Target As Range)
    
    Const TARGET_RANGE As String = "I13:I20"
    Const HIDE_COLUMN As Variant = "U"
    
    Dim arrSearch() As Variant: arrSearch = Array(2, 3) 'the values to be searched (you can place here as many you need)
    Dim El As Variant, boolFound As Boolean             'other necessary variables
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Target.Worksheet
    Dim trg As Range: Set trg = ws.Range(TARGET_RANGE)
    Dim irg As Range: Set irg = Intersect(trg, Target)
    If irg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
       
    With ws.Columns(HIDE_COLUMN)
        For Each El In arrSearch
            If IsNumeric(Application.match(El, trg, 0)) Then
                boolFound = True: Exit For
            End If
        Next El
        If boolFound Then
                If .Hidden Then .Hidden = False
        Else
                If Not .Hidden Then .Hidden = True
        End If
    End With

End Sub
```

Send some feedback after testing it, please.